# How to use group by with multiple table joins in Entity framework core

Tags: join, group-by, entity-framework-core

I am trying to convert below query in entity framework core but not able to access  field in select query  after apply group by.

```
Select ProdCatg.Category As [Category]
,Prod.FKProdCatgID As [FKProdCatgID]
,SUM(Dtl.Qty + LD.ProdConv1 + Trn.CashAmt   ) As [DistributionRateValue]            
From tblSalesInv_Dtl Dtl  
Left Join tblSalesInv_Trn Trn on Trn.PKID=Dtl.FKID And Trn.FKSeriesID=Dtl.FKSeriesID
 Left Join tblProdLot_Dtl LD on Dtl.FKLotID=LD.PKLotID And LD.FKProdID=Dtl.FKProdID
Left Join tblProd_Mas Prod ON PKProdID=Dtl.FKProdID
Left Join tblProdCatg_Mas ProdCatg On PKProdCatgID=Prod.FKProdCatgID                         
 Where Trn.DraftMode=0     
 Group By Prod.FKProdCatgID,ProdCatg.Category                        
 Order By Category
```

I am trying convert like this but but not able to access  `Dtl.Qty + LD.ProdConv1 + Trn.CashAmt`fields

```
var result1 = (from dtl in _context.TblSalesInvDtl
                      join ser in lstSeries on dtl.FkseriesId equals ser
                      join trn in _context.TblSalesInvTrn on new { s1 = dtl.Fkid, s2 = ser } equals new { s1 = trn.Pkid, s2 = trn.FkseriesId }
                      join lot in _context.TblProdLotDtl on new { s1 = dtl.FklotId, s2 = dtl.FkprodId } equals new { s1 = lot.PklotId, s2 = lot.FkprodId }
                      join p in _context.TblProdMas on dtl.FkprodId equals p.PkprodId into pr
                      from Prod in pr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join pl in _context.TblProdMas on dtl.FklinkedProdId equals pl.PkprodId into plid
                      from ProdLinked in plid.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join t in _context.TblTaxMas on dtl.FktaxId equals t.PktaxId into tid
                      from Tax in tid.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join c in _context.TblProdCatgMas on Prod.FkprodCatgId equals c.PkprodCatgId into cid
                      from Catg in cid.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where trn.EntryDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1-12-2018")
                      group Catg by new { Prod.FkprodCatgId, Catg.Category } into gb
                      //, dtl, lot, Prod
                      select new
                      {

                          CategoryName = gb.FirstOrDefault().Category,
                           DistributionRateValue = gb.Sum(a => (gb.Key.dtl.Qty + gb.Key.lot.ProdConv1+ gb.Key.lot.CashAmt)),
                          FKProdCatgID= gb.Key.Prod.FkprodCatgId,

                      }

                      ).ToList();
```

can anybody help me how can I access multiple table fields in  sum with groupby in entity framework core.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Done Please check now